# fs.readdirSync include subdirectories

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to change my code to include files in subdirectories as well:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

I found a solution that looks a bit abstract to me, when I tried to implement it, I got a error, this is what I tried:

```
const { readdirSync, statSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

const dirs = p => readdirSync(p).filter(f => statSync(join(p, f)).isDirectory())

const commandFiles = ('./commands');

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './commands/.'
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work with

```
const fs = require('fs');

const walk = function(dir) {
    let results = [];
    const list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    list.forEach(function(file) {
        file = dir + '/' + file;
        file_type = file.split(".").pop();
        file_name = file.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
        const stat = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) { 
            results = results.concat(walk(file));
        } else { 
            if (file_type == "js") results.push(file);
        }
    });
    return results;
}

const commandFiles = walk('./commands');

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`${file}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use __dirname

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```